# Object size increases hugely when transposing a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, memory, transpose

I have a data frame of ca. 50,000 RNA transcripts in rows, with 10,000 different samples in columns. The size of the data frame is 4.9GB.

I then have to transpose the data in order to subset it properly later:

`df <- data.frame(t(df))`

After the transpose, the object size has ballooned to 70GB. Why is this happening? Should transposing data really change the file size that much?

`str()` of the first 20 columns:

```
str(df[1:20])
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   56202 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ X1                      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Name                    : chr  "ENSG00000223972.4" "ENSG00000227232.4" "ENSG00000243485.2" "ENSG00000237613.2" ...
 $ Description             : chr  "DDX11L1" "WASH7P" "MIR1302-11" "FAM138A" ...
 $ GTEX-1117F-0226-SM-5GZZ7: num  0.1082 21.4 0.1602 0.0505 0 ...
 $ GTEX-111CU-1826-SM-5GZYN: num  0.1158 11.03 0.0643 0 0 ...
 $ GTEX-111FC-0226-SM-5N9B8: num  0.021 16.75 0.0467 0.0295 0 ...
 $ GTEX-111VG-2326-SM-5N9BK: num  0.0233 8.172 0 0.0326 0 ...
 $ GTEX-111YS-2426-SM-5GZZQ: num  0 7.658 0.0586 0 0 ...
 $ GTEX-1122O-2026-SM-5NQ91: num  0.0464 9.372 0 0 0 ...
 $ GTEX-1128S-2126-SM-5H12U: num  0.0308 10.08 0.1367 0.0861 0.1108 ...
 $ GTEX-113IC-0226-SM-5HL5C: num  0.0936 13.56 0.2079 0.131 0.0562 ...
 $ GTEX-117YX-2226-SM-5EGJJ: num  0.121 9.889 0.0537 0.0677 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11DXW-0326-SM-5H11W: num  0.0286 9.121 0.0635 0 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11DXX-2326-SM-5Q5A2: num  0 6.698 0.0508 0.032 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11DZ1-0226-SM-5A5KF: num  0.0237 9.835 0 0.0664 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11EI6-0226-SM-5EQ64: num  0.0802 13.1 0 0 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11EM3-2326-SM-5H12B: num  0.0223 8.904 0.0496 0.0625 0.0402 ...
 $ GTEX-11EMC-2826-SM-5PNY6: num  0.0189 16.59 0 0.0265 0.034 ...
 $ GTEX-11EQ8-0226-SM-5EQ5G: num  0.0931 15.1 0.0689 0.0869 0 ...
 $ GTEX-11EQ9-2526-SM-5HL66: num  0.0777 9.838 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you write that:

> I then have to transpose this dataset in order to subset it properly later,

To be honest, I doubt you have to. Thus, this *may* be an XY-problem. That said, I think could be of general interest to dissect the issue.

---

The increase in object size is most likely due to that the `class` of the object before and after transposing has changed, together with the fact that objects of different class have different size.

I will try to illustrate this with some examples. We begin with the change of class.

Create a toy data frame with a structure resembling yours, a few character columns and several numeric columns:

```
# set number of rows and columns
nr <- 5
nc <- 5

set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x = sample(letters, nr, replace = TRUE),
                y = sample(letters, nr, replace = TRUE),
                matrix(runif(nr * nc), nrow = nr),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Transpose it:

```
d_t <- t(d)
```

Check the `str`ucture of the original data and its transposed sibling:

```
str(d)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ x : chr  "g" "j" "o" "x" ...
# $ y : chr  "x" "y" "r" "q" ...
# $ X1: num  0.206 0.177 0.687 0.384 0.77
# $ X2: num  0.498 0.718 0.992 0.38 0.777
# $ X3: num  0.935 0.212 0.652 0.126 0.267
# $ X4: num  0.3861 0.0134 0.3824 0.8697 0.3403
# $ X5: num  0.482 0.6 0.494 0.186 0.827

str(d_t)
# chr [1:7, 1:5] "g" "x" "0.2059746" "0.4976992" ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:7] "x" "y" "X1" "X2" ...
#  ..$ : NULL
```

The data frame has became a character matrix. How did this happen? Well, check the help text for the transpose method for data frames: `?t.data.frame`:

> A data frame is first coerced to a matrix: see `as.matrix`.

OK, see `?as.matrix`:

> The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and **any** non-(numeric/logical/complex) column [...]

Whereas a data frame is a list where each column can be of *different* class, a matrix is just a vector with dimensions, which can hold only *one* class. Thus, because you have at least one character column, i.e. a non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, your data frame is coerced to a character matrix as a result of `t`ranspose. Then you coerce the matrix to data frame, where all columns are character (or `factor`, depending on your `stringsAsFactors` setting) - check `str(data.frame(d_t))`.

---

In the second step, the size of different objects is compared. Start with the data frame and its transpose, as created above:

```
# original data frame
object.size(d)
# 2360 bytes

# transposed df - a character matrix
object.size(d_t)
# 3280 bytes
```

The transposed object is clearly larger. If we increase the number rows and the number of numeric columns to mimic your data better, the relative difference is even larger:

```
nr <- 56202
nc <- 20 

object.size(d)
# 9897712 bytes
object.size(d_t)
# 78299656 bytes
```

---

Because the number of elements is the same in the original and transposed data, the (memory) size of each individual element must differ. Let's check the size of `integer`, `numeric`, and `character` vectors of the same length. First, vectors with one-digit values and a corresponding vector of one-character elements:

```
onedigit_int <- sample(1:9, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
onedigit_num <- as.numeric(onedigit_int)
onedigit_char <- as.character(onedigit_int)    

object.size(onedigit_int)
# 40048 bytes

object.size(onedigit_num)
# 80048 bytes

object.size(onedigit_char)
# 80552 bytes
```

For the single digits/characters, `integer` vectors occupy 4 bytes per element, and `numeric` and `character` vectors 8 bytes per element. The single-character vector does *not* require more memory than the numeric vector. Does this mean that we can reject the idea that the increase in total size is explained by the coercion of a large number of numeric variables to character? Well, we need to check what happens with vectors with multi-digits (which you seem to have) and their corresponding vectors of multi-character strings:

```
multidigit_int <- sample(1:1e6, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
multidigit_num <- as.numeric(multidigit_int)
multidigit_char <- as.character(multidigit_int)

object.size(multidigit_int)
# 40048 bytes

object.size(multidigit_num)
# 80048 bytes

object.size(multidigit_char)
# 637360 bytes
```

The integer vector still occupies 4 bytes for each element, the numeric vector still occupies 8 bytes for each element. However, the size per element in the character vector is *larger* for larger strings.

Thus, the transpose coerced your data frame to a character matrix, and the size of each character element is larger than its corresponding numeric element.

Transposing a data frame with columns of *different* class is very rarely sensible. And if *all* columns are of *same* class, then we may just as well use a matrix from the start.

---

Read more about how much memory is used to store different objects in [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! And you were right in that it was the object type that was the problem. I did actually manage to get the size down myself as I was wrangling the data all afternoon and converting it back to numbers and factors, but your explanation has helped me understand WHY this makes such a difference.

You said that you didn't think I would need to transpose it in the first place, but I was doing this as I wanted to merge in with another file in order to subset on tissue type. The only way I know how to subset needs the samples in rows and genes in columns, hence the transpose.

Comment: Hi @PhilD Thanks for your feedback. Regarding your need (or not ;) ) for transpose, without seeing your data and a more thorough description on what you try to aceive, I can only guess (hence my "_may_"). Still, if you allow me to guess, it sounds that an alternative you may consider is to melt your data from wide to long. Then merge/subset. Cheers